# SQLite and PHP connection

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am trying to connect the SQLite studio browser to fetch contents in spiceworks databse backup using PHP. I am confused after having read so many forums as to what exact code ill have to put up for connecting the SQLite and PHP.

I presume it is

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:C:\Program Files (x86)\Spiceworks\spiceworks_prod.db');
```

However my PHP code stops right there! I am confused as to what I need to expect as response on the PHP page

Comment: Can you add error/exception handling in your code like this: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#4.2 and see what you get ?

Comment: Well, I did that. The line where we assign the PDO to the DBH variable, the code apparently stops there and doesnt go further!

Comment: Well, that might be a case of an uncaught exception and suppressed error reporting …